# Expressing sums of powers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to solve this question but I'm not really understanding how to continue, I would greatly appreciate some kind of tip.

**The Question**

The formula for $1^2 + \cdots + n^2$ may be derived as follows.  We begin with the formula $$(k+1)^3 - k^3 = 3k^2 + 3k + 1$$

Writing this formula for $k=1,\ldots,n$ and adding we obtain an expression.

Thus we can find $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2$ if we already know $\sum_{k=1}^n k$.

Use this method to find $1^3 + \cdots + n^3$.

I am confused about this method.  How did they get the formula to begin with, and what formula am I supposed to use for $1^3 + \cdots + n^3$?

EDIT: I noted that they did already hint at $k^2$ being expressed from $k^1$, but we can't square $k^1$ into $k^3$

Comment: $(k+1)^4-k^4=4k^3+6k^2+4k+1$

Comment: How did you get that expression? I noted that you basically did $(k+1)^{(3+1)}$ but what reason would there be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula is the Binomial Theorem, or just multiplication: $(k+1)^3=k^3+3k^2+3k+1$. This can be rewritten as 
$$(k+1)^3-k^3=3k^2+3k+1.$$

The corresponding formula for fourth powers is $(k+1)^4=k^4+4k^3+6k^2+4k+1$. It yields the identity 
$$(k+1)^4-k^4=4k^3+6k^2+4k+1.$$
That can be used to give a telescoping argument for the sum of the first $n$ cubes, much like the telescoping argument for the sum of the first $n$ squares. Sum both sides from $k=1$ to $k=n$. On the right, there is almost total cancellation, and we get
$$(n+1)^4-1=4\sum_1^n k^3+6\sum_1^n k^2+4\sum_1^n k +\sum_1^n 1.\tag{1}$$
Now a fair bit of messy algebra gets us $\sum_1^n k^3$, since we have formulas for every other sum in (1).

In general, the Binomial Theorem is the assertion that if $m$ is a positive integer, then
$$\small (x+y)^m=\binom{m}{0}x^m +\binom{m}{1}x^{m-1}y+\binom{m}{2}x^{m-2}y^2+\cdots +\binom{m}{m-1}xy^{m-1}+\binom{m}{m}y^m.$$

**Remark:** It will turn out that 
$$1^3+2^3+\cdots+n^3=\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2.$$
Once we have guessed this formula, it can be proved more easily by induction.

Comment: Couldn't we just skip all of the above steps and start with $\sum_j^n j^3$ because it is logical to do so?  It technically is the representation of the cubes of the sums from j = 1 to j = n

Comment: We are looking for a *closed form* expression for $\sum_1^n j^3$. The trick using $(k+1)^4-k^4$ is one way of getting such a closed form.

Comment: Isn't expressing $k^3$ as $(k+1)^4 - k^4 = 4k^3 + 6k^2 + 4k + 1$ incorrect? Say k = 3, k^3 = 27, but the above expression gives 256 - 81 = 108+54+12+1.  There is no way to add any of this together to get 27.

Comment: Note that $256-81=175$ while $108+54+12+1=175$, so the equation is correct when $k=3$. It is in fact correct for all $k$.

Comment: Yes, but doesn't that have nothing to do with k^3? i.e. it has no relation to the sum of k^3 from i = 1 to n

Comment: To evaluate further, it kind of feels like they just randomly picked the binomial theorem.  I can't really see any relation that it has to finding the sum of the squares/cubes.  I'm not sure if I'm dumb for not seeing some obvious pattern, or if I am right and they just decided to one day randomly pick this and found out one of its unique properties by accident.

Comment: Yes it does, that is mentioned in the answer I gave to your question. Sum both sides of the identity from $k=1$ to $k=n$. On the left, by telescoping we get $(n+1)^4-1$. On the right, we get $4\sum k^3+6\sum k^2+4\sum k+\sum 1$. We know $\sum k^2$, $\sum k$, and $\sum 1$, so we can figure out $\sum k^3$. This was already dealt with in the answer.

Comment: In reply to your previous comment, well, it is a trick that works. There are other tricks that will let us get at the answer.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
 1^3-0^3=3*0^2+3*0+1\\2^3-1^3=3*1^2+3*1+1\\...\\(n+1)^3-n^3=3*n^3+3*n+1
\end{align}
Now sum all of the equalities.
\begin{align}
 (n+1)^3=3\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2+3\sum_{k=1}^{n}k+(n+1)
\end{align}
Now you can proceed further.